# Android : why the second if statement not working in this Java file ?? is it the right way?

Tags: android, if-statement

In this code second if not checking and directly it's going to else block But I need to check the first if condition and then second if condition and then else but here second if condition not checking and else block means going to next activity.

```
if (selectedDate.equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "PLEASE SELECT DATE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String queryString = "class_id=" + selectedClassId + "&section_id=" + selectedSectionId+"attend_date=" + selectedDate;
    String data1 = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("at_date",queryString);
    System.out.println(data1);

    if((data1.startsWith("Specified section"))){
        tv2.setText(data1);
        return;
    }

    tv2.setText("");
}
else {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Attend.class);
    i.putExtra("class_id",selectedClassId);
    i.putExtra("section_id",selectedSectionId);
    i.putExtra("attend_date",selectedDate);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to achieve. Use puncuation, and tell us EXACTLY what you need to happen when code is executed

Comment: first if condition if I am not selected any thing it's checking the first if condition.But second if condition I want to excute

Comment: The String data1 in the 2nd If statement relies on data parsed in the 1st if condition. It cannot be executed unless the 1st if block passes requirements (in your case, if it's empty)

Answer (score 0):

try with below code:

```
if (selectedDate..trim().length()<=0) {
    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "PLEASE SELECT DATE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String queryString = "class_id=" + selectedClassId + "&section_id=" + selectedSectionId+"attend_date=" + selectedDate;
    String data1 = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("at_date",queryString);
    System.out.println(data1);

    if((data1.startsWith("Specified section"))){
        tv2.setText(data1);
        return;
    }

    tv2.setText("");
}
else {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Attend.class);
    i.putExtra("class_id",selectedClassId);
    i.putExtra("section_id",selectedSectionId);
    i.putExtra("attend_date",selectedDate);
    startActivity(i);
}
```